# Appcelerator - Problem on Android with google maps and Open Street Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, webview, titanium, appcelerator

I'm developing an app with appcelerator. In this app, i'm using the module ti.map to show a map of the city. I have created the api key and everything else. My problem is that when i try to open the map on android ( on IOS it works fine ), the app hangs and doesn't respond...

After some time the alert box appears telling my that my app doesn't respond and if i want to close it. If i remove the amp it works correctly....

I thought that my problem would come because i didn't have a billing account for google maps, so i tried to load a webview ( with a user agent of mozilla ), to see if i could load a map, but it didn't work, the app opened the view but it was white ( at least it responded).

Then i tried with a link to openstreetmap in a webview, with also didn't work.... ( the same link with an external browser on the device works...)

So.... i don't know what to do.... Any help?

In other apps that i have developed i never encountered this problem... ( i developed one 2 months ago that had maps and it worked fine...)

Appcelerator SDK - 7.4.1
Ti.Map module version - 4.3.1

Tested on:
genimotion - Samsung Galaxy 6 ( with opengapps)
genimotion - Samsung Galaxy 8 ( with opengapps)
Device - Samsung Galaxy 6
Device - Samsung Galaxy j6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The problem comes when the module of Ti.map and Ti.playservices, are both on the app. After removing Ti.playservices the map and the app worked.